# Should questions on the reopen review queue show why they were closed?

Tags: feature-request

When reviewing the *Reopen* review queue, I find my self having to open the question it self on another tab, in order to check why the question was close in the first place, so I can know if the edit fixes that. I think this is just extra effort (not much, but still) and should be fixed.

Comment: This would probably have to be a network wide change, probably better put on http://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Well, yeah, but they're mean :( sometimes; I'll migrate it later...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For questions that were edited after the question was closed (thus the automatic reopen review), it will say at the top of the review: "This question was edited after it was closed."

For all other questions in the review queue you can simply click on the *Question (revised)* button. Then look at the close reason listed below the question.
[image: reopen review]

---

I just did a [reopen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/14139) for "edited after it was closed." As you can see in the screen shot after clicking on the *Question (revised)* button the close reason *is* listed below the question.
[image: reopen review page]

Comment: And that's why I didn't post it to meta.stackexchange.com - it was a derp on my part...

Comment: Well at least anyone on this site with the same problem should be able to find an answer now.

Comment: @David Wait.. Yeah, that was the problem - it doesn't show the close reason if it was edited after being closed, so I can't know if the edited fixes the question.

Comment: @someonewithpc see my edited answer.